# Can I use a trigger in CosmosDB (Graph API) to automatically create an edge based on the document payload?

Tags: graph, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection of json documents in CosmosDB that can contain references to other documents in the collection (by id).

I'd like to automatically manage graph edges between these documents by using triggers that run whenever a doc is created/updated/deleted.

Can I access the Gremlin API from Javascript inside the trigger function?

Is there any documentation for triggers in the context of graphs? I couldn't find any.

A dirtier alternative would be to just "manually" create the edge document in the trigger but this would break if the CosmosDB team change the underlying format of the documents describing the edges.

Answer (score 1):

The [Cosmos DB Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function) will probably work and it will give you a set of Documents which you might need to process first.

Since the Trigger is listening to the [Change Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed) you will get Documents that represent any insertion / update on the Collection. In the case of a Graph, these can be Vertices or Edges, so you might need to first detect what type of Document it is to work with it.

As for persisting the new relationship, the [DocumentDB Output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-documentdb#docdboutput) might not work for you, because like you said, the internal representation might change. But what you can do is include in your Azure Function some [C# / Node Gremlin library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#using-nuget-packages) and use it to talk to the Cosmos DB Graph API directly.

Comment: OP seems to be referring to the actual trigger functionality included in Cosmos, not an Azure Function trigger. In the case of database level triggers you get automatic transaction scoping and ACID guarantees which may be important to his workload

Comment: Good point, I thought he was referring to the new CosmosDB Trigger with Azure Functions, I'll delete the answer if the OP confirms that's not the case :)

Answer (score 1):

Graph API is currently not supported within UDFs/database triggers/stored procedures, and we don't have a timeline for when this will be supported.

The next best approach is manually create the graph elements as you described.